# Bit extraction and Steganography

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, steganography

I am playing around with steganography. I am trying to pull a text file from a image. I am able to read the file, get the bits, but I have an issue with the extraction of these bits.

```
int getbits( pixel p) {
    return p & 0x03;   
}

char extract ( pixel* image ) {
    static int postion;
    postion = 0;

    postion = *image;

    postion++;

    char curChar;
    curChar = '\0';
    for(int i = 0; i<4; ++i) {
        curChar = curChar << 2;
        curChar = curChar | getbits(postion);
    }
    return curChar;
}
```

Pixel is an unsigned char. I have loop that calls `extract()` and `fputc(3)` the return value. I feel like I am getting garbage from these bits. Which causes me to have massive (1.5 gig) txt files in return.

```
void decode( PgmType* pgm, char output[80] )
{
FILE*outstream;
int i, length;

outstream = fopen(output, "w");

if(!outstream)
{
    fatal("Could not open");
}
for(i=0; i < 16; ++i)
{
    length = length << 2;
    length = length | getbits(*pgm->image);
}
if ((length* 4) < (pgm->width * pgm->height))
{
    fatal("File Too Big");
}
for (i = 0 ;i<length; ++i)
{
    fputc(extract(pgm->image), outstream);

}
fclose(outstream);

}
```

Comment: Stenography or **Steganography** ?

Comment: Show the loop that calls extract - since you should demonstrate that you are correctly looping through the image.

Comment: @borrible I included the loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only actually reading the first pixel in the image - [Edit] because while you are trying to use a static var to keep count, as Oli points out you're immediately overwriting it.

Instead use position to track your count; but hold the data in another var:

Instead `extract()` should look something like:

```
char extract ( pixel* image )
{
   static int postion = 0;

   pixel data = image[position];

   postion++;

   // use 'data' for processing
}
```

Comment: This is a red herring; the OP is immediately overwriting `position` with `*image`...

Comment: @Joe: I assume that you are calling extract more times than there are pixels in your image array. Can you see on which iteration you get the error?

Comment: @Dave it is not the first one it is creating a file and just over runs the array

Comment: @Dave I also had to place the position++ in the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Dave Rigby's [excellent diagnosis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6565510/bit-extraction-and-steganography/6565522#6565522) is correct, but passing `position` as a parameter (and *not* incrementing it here) would lead to easier to understand and more flexible routines:

```
char extract ( pixel* image, int position ) {
    char curChar = '\0';
    for(int i = 0; i<4; ++i) {
        curChar = curChar << 2;
        curChar = curChar | getbits(postion);
    }
    return curChar;
}

char *build_string(pixel *image) {
    int i;
    char *ret = malloc(SECRET_SIZE);
    for (i=0; i<SECRET_SIZE; i++) {
        ret[i]=extract(image, i);
    }
    ret[i] = '\0';
    return ret;
}
```

Then, when you realize that changing all the pixels in a line makes it pretty obvious, and you'd rather use pixels located at Fibonacci values, the change is easy to make:

```
char *build_string_via_fib(pixel *image) {
    int i;
    char *ret = malloc(SECRET_SIZE);

    for (i=0; i<SECRET_SIZE; i++) {
        ret[i]=extract(image, fib(i));
    }
    ret[i]='\0';
    return ret;
}
```

You *could* stuff the Fibonacci computation into your `extract()` routine too, but decomposing functions into the smallest, most useful, pieces, gives you excellent legibility, excellent testability, and best chances for future code re-use.